# How to write .htaccess for main folder and sub folder for PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP project but it displays on live server 500 error.

Project structure Look like this,

Home - Main folder it contains two subfolder 
  1. admin 1
  2. admin 2

In URL not display PHP Extension

### 1. .htaccess try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(?!404\.html)$ - [L,NC,R=404]  
 </IfModule>
```

### 2. .htaccess try

```
RewriteOptions inherit
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on

### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"

RewriteRule ^(?!404\.html)$ - [L,NC,R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove php extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```